# How to switch position from left to bottom without using absolute positioning and negative margins?

Tags: html, css

By using the selector .icon-bottom, how should I position an icon into the bottom?
I tried using absolute/relative position but elements inside li doesn't behave properly. I even used negative margins. Please help me play with it. thanks!
[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/x9bt3d1g/2/)

```
  <ul class="icon-bottom">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-beer"></i>tab2</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just put the `<i>` elements after the content?

Comment: I did that, pls see the fiddle. But I should use css to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution, use table.

```css
li { display:inline-block;border:1px solid #ddd }
li a { text-align:center;padding:10px 20px;display:table }
li a .fa{ display:table-footer-group; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="icon-bottom">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>tab1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-beer"></i>tab2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the most flexible solution.

Comment: You are welcome. I ran into this problem before too.

Answer (score 1):

you could use flex and order or manage a little **work around** with `float` and `clear` specifities.

---

float work around:

```css
li {
    display:inline-block; 
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #ddd
}
li a { 
    padding:10px 20px;
}
/*outcome U wanted */
.icon-bottom li:before {
    content:'';
    float:left;
    height:1.6em;
}
.fa {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <ul class="icon-bottom">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-beer"></i>tab2</a></li>
      </ul>
```

the idea is to clear a floatting element below an height set via a floatting pseudo. room left on top will be used by text in the natural flow as long as it finds room ,else it will drop under.

---

the flex attitude :)

```css
li {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #ddd
}
li a {
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 20px;
    display:block
}
/*outcome I wanted */
 li a  {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}

.fa {
    order:2
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <ul class="icon-bottom">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-beer"></i>tab2</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming altering the markup is not possible, one possible option is to use `relative` positioning on the icons and setting negative top margin and a bottom padding to the anchor tags:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/x9bt3d1g/4/)**

```css
.icon-bottom a {
    line-height: 1.2;
    margin-top: -1.2em;
    padding-bottom: 1.8em;
}

.icon-bottom i {
    position: relative;
    top: 2.4em;
}
```

Preview:

```css
.icon-bottom a {
    line-height: 1.2;
    margin-top: -1.2em;
    padding-bottom: 1.8em;
}

.icon-bottom i {
    position: relative;
    top: 2.4em;
}

li { display:inline-block;border:1px solid #ddd }
li a { text-align:center;padding:10px 20px;display:block }

/*outcome I wanted */
li a .fa{ display:block }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h2>Initial position</h2>
<ul class="icon-bottom">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>tab1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-beer"></i>tab2</a></li>
</ul>
```